# Spawned process from java inherits parent socket on FreeBSD

Tags: java, sockets, fork, freebsd

I have Spring (SprintBoot) application, runs as service and listens port 80 on FreeBSD.

```
$ sockstat -4 -l | grep 80
root java 98931 30 tcp4 6 *:80 *:*
```

I am starting another service (for example, samba) from my service, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/sbin/service samba_server start")
```

and get this:

```
$ sockstat -4 -l | grep 80
root smbd 99735 30 tcp4 6 *:80 *:*
root nmbd 99730 30 tcp4 6 *:80 *:*
root java 98931 30 tcp4 6 *:80 *:*
```

Same with other service. After killing my service, port 80 remains occupied. Why is this happening? Does exec() uses fork with full resource inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vfork / posix_spawn helped.
Used this library with java binding https://github.com/axiak/java_posix_spawn